# CodeIgniter AJAX results writing to DIV

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have used this method in the past, but never with CodeIgniter.  I'm just working on figuring out CI.

I have a very basic AJAX call for database results formatted in a datagrid.

Watching in the console, the expected results are showing up, however I just can't figure out why it won't write to my `<div>`. (I do get the alert that you see in the `.complete` below)

jQuery:

```
    var myOnload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://contacts.drumichael.xyz/contacts/load_contacts',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {get_it: 'yes'},
    }).complete(function(data) {
        $(".the_list").html(data);
        alert('done');
    });
};
myOnload();
```

The controller looks like this: (simplified)

```
public function load_contacts() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM contacts_list");
    $array = $query->result();

    $return = '';

    $return .= '<div class="panel-heading text-right"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp;New Contact</a></div>';
    $return .= '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">';
    $return .= '    <thead>';
    $return .= '        <tr>';
    $return .= '            <th></th>';
    $return .= '            <th>Last Name</th>';
    $return .= '            <th>First Name</th>';
    $return .= '            <th>Cell</th>';
    $return .= '            <th>Home</th>';
    $return .= '            <th>Address 1</th>';
    $return .= '            <th>Email</th>';
    $return .= '            <th>URL</th>';
    $return .= '            <th></th>';
    $return .= '        </tr>';
    $return .= '    </thead>';
    $return .= '    <tbody>';

            if(!empty($array)) {    
                foreach($array as $row) {
                    $return .= '<tr>';
                        $return .= '<td><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></td>';
                        $return .= '<td>'.$row->lname.'</td>';
                        $return .= '<td>'.$row->fname.'</td>';
                        $return .= '<td>'.$row->phone1.'</td>';
                        $return .= '<td>'.$row->phone2.'</td>';
                        $return .= '<td>' .$row->address1. ' ' .$row->city.', ' .$row->state. ' ' .$row->zip. '</td>';
                        $return .= '<td>'.$row->email.'</td>';
                        $return .= '<td>'.$row->url.'</td>';
                        $return .= '<td><a href="" class="btn-delete" data-rec-id="'.$row->id.'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
                    $return .= '</tr>';
                }
            } else {
                $return .= '<tr><td colspan="9">You don\'t have any contacts yet! Why not create some?</td></tr>';
            }


        $return .= '</tbody></table></div>';


    echo $return; 
}
```

In the view, I have `<div class="the_list"></div>`, however it never gets replaced with the HTML.  Like I said earlier, I can see the HTML in the response section within my console in Firefox.  Any ideas on what I've got wrong?

Comment: Are you getting your expected data? Have you `var_dumped` your return in your view or controller? 

Another important note is that you should really only use database functions in the model. At least from a semantic standpoint it's a bit taboo to call database queries in your controllers.

Comment: I logged the result to console and figured out that I needed to use data['responseText'], instead of just 'data'.  Also, I do use model, but when I started trying to debug this issue I pulled this out into the controller just to eliminate some possible issues.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not specific for code Igniter, the problem in your ajax call. 
You are using `.complete` method which will return XMLHttpRequest object. 
So, in your case you can use `

> data.responseText

It will return the responded text. So, the modified code will be.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myOnload = function(){
          $.ajax({
             url: 'http://contacts.drumichael.xyz/contacts/load_contacts',
             type: 'post',
             dataType: 'json', // need not to specify if you are not returning json 
             data: {get_it: 'yes'},
          }).complete(function(data, xhr, settings) {
            $(".the_list").html(data.responseText);
            alert('done');
          });
       };
     myOnload();
   });
```